# The second most populated city in each country. (MySQL - Homework Question)

Tags: mysql

I am trying to understand how to do this problem but unable to understand.

The question is: ***What the second most populated city in each country.***

Here is what I've gotten written up so far:

```
SELECT c1.Name, c1.population
FROM city c1
WHERE c1.population = 
(SELECT MAX(c1.population)
FROM city c1 
WHERE c1.population GROUP BY c1.CountryCode < 
(SELECT MAX(c1.population) FROM city c1 GROUP BY c1.CountryCode));
```

This is not working and unable to get the answer.

Schema:

```
Country(NAME,CODE,CONTINENT, REGION, SUFACEAREA, INDEPYEAR, POPULATION, LIFEEXPECT, GNP, GNPID, LOCALNAME)
CountryLanguage(Percentage, CountryCode, Language)
City(ID, NAME, COUNTRYCODE, DISTRICT, POPULATION)
```

I expect the output to provide me the results for a query for the most populated city in each country.

Comment: Replace 'not working' with whatever response was received. Its never a useful phrase to use when asking for help.

Comment: Are you allowed to use MySQL-8.0 window functions?

Comment: i suggest you reading [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Comment: Hint: A simple MySQL only "cheat" would be to use `GROUP_CONCAT()` and (nested) `SUBSTRING_INDEX()` functions.. Look into the manual and read about the functions options you will understand how and why.

Answer (score 1):

You did not provide the exact schema for the `city` table so I improvised. This should do the trick:

```sql
# City table
CREATE TABLE city (
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  name varchar(25),
  population INT
);
```

```sql
SELECT 
  c2.*
FROM 
  city AS c1
  JOIN city AS c2 ON c2.population <c1.population
GROUP BY c2.id
ORDER BY c2.population DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Hope this helps,

Comment: I updated the schema, in my question. I tried your solution however I only get one answer and not for each country. It only gives for one country, so I remove the limit 1, but that still does not allow me to group by country.